# Find street intersections within an area in using Google Maps API

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, graph

Given a square area, what is the best way to find the approximate coordinates of every street intersection within the given area ?

Comment: It can be done in a number of ways, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: One that I'm going to see how it works is to determine all the street names in the area by sampling the area and then determine all their intersections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no description of your application, I can't tell if you need to use Google Maps or if another data source would answer your needs.
If http://openstreetmap.org fulfills the requirements of your application, then it's easy:

- the OSM API has a request to pull data from a rectangular region. You get XML data.
- filter this data to keep only the street you are interested in, probably the "key=highway" tags
- filter this to keep only the points belonging to two or more lines.

Please disregard this if Google Maps is a requirement.

But still: since the roads exist independently of the database, the above method will yield roads intersections (in lat/long coordinates) with a pretty high correlation with what you would get from Google maps ;-) You can then use those points to display them over a Google map, knowing that both datasets aren't identical so it won't be perfect.

Comment: Ok, I have downloaded the XML file of the rectangular region. How Exactly do i create a filter to keep only the points belonging to two or more lines?

I mean, how do I even start?
Which tool do you recommend I use?

Comment: I'd recommend to use an xml library of your favorite language.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the easiest method but I used a seperate database of our countries roads with their linestrings.
I took the first and last points of each line string, then counted the number of roads within 50 m of each start/end point. I then took the nodes from navigation route and used these to compare the number of roads intersecting with each node. I then looked at the direction each start point and the next point along that road, which gives you direction. from that with a bit of maths you can work out the number and angle of the roads at the next intersection. I then made a road rules application that tells you which vehicles to give way to

Comment: It would be helpful if you added psuedo code. The verbal description is not easy to read.