# Get all intersections around location in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, intersection

is there some API to get street intersection (like coordinates, type of road etc.) from Google Map.

I googled about it and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965090/get-list-of-all-intersections-in-a-city) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395874/find-street-intersections-within-an-area-in-using-google-maps-api) but both is concerned about Open Street Map - I need it for my android device so I strongly **need Google Maps**.

Comment: I don't think so google maps provide that much of data you can use OSM data while still using Google Map.

Comment: I know it is solution from links above, but I was wonder if I can get it directly from Google Map. (because I read somewhere that Google maps and OSM arent in 1:1 - small deviation)

Comment: Contact google and ask if they provide this data to their premium customers! Other wise you can shift to osm base map.

Comment: How is possible to contact Google - I was searching for some direct email but I havent found anything yet